# SQL server Replication and EDM

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, replication

For high availability, our company is adding a new webserver and sql server. We will be doing P2P replication for making the two SQL servers consistent. However, we are using EDM in our application and it is based on the existing server. If we add another SQL server, do I need to create another set of EDM for the second database. Maintaining 2 edmx files will be a nightmare. And may be in future for scaibility purposes we add another SQL server. There must be a better way then having a separate EDMX file for each SQl server. Furthermore, for the already existing code that accesses the database using EDM, how should I modify it so that it selects the correct database and hence it's EDM. Presently, I have code like:

using (var context = new MyCOmpanyModel.MyCompanyEntities()) { .... }

I don't want to change this on every page which accesses EDM. There must be a better way of selecting the SQL server (or Entities) and setting them may be in a base Page class or anything like that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are going to replicate data between same database server versions hosting the database with the same schema = there is no need to change EDM the only needed change should be connection string for the second web server.

I'm wonder why did you choose this solution? Imho to achieve high availability companies usually go to Failover clustering (active/passive) for a database and load balancing for a web server. Web server load balancing is transparent to clients and failover clustering is transparent to web server. Failover cluster uses shared NAS or SAN storage (with its own high availability features like RAID arrays and hot swaps). In the scenario of active/passive cluster you should require only SQL server licenses for active server (if this haven't changed recently).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. So this is what you are suggesting:

```
<add name="MainDB" 
 connectionString="metadata=res://*/MainDB..." 
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"   />
<add name="OtherDB" 
 connectionString="metadata=res://*/MainDB..." 
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

string connectionStringKey;


if(Server == 1)  
  connectionStringKey = "MainDB";
else
   connectionStringKey = "OtherDB";

        using (var context = new MainDB("name=" + connectionStringKey))
        {
        }
```

I don't want to put the above check server code on almost every page. It will be a big headache if we add one more sql server to the netwrok later. Is there a better way of setting the server connectionstring or the ObjectContext obj once in the application and just forget about it.

Regarding your suggestion doing clustering for the database server, clustering is expensive. It requires additional hardware and software. p2P replication doesn't seem to be that expensive. However, thanks for the suggestion.